# Data packages access practices

Tags: c++, c

I am working with a file package and to perform different actions with it I would like to read different values from the file header. To access this information, my instructor told me make a array of type `char` and than access whatever data I need by going to the offset position of my data on the package and type casting it to the appropriate datatype.

I want to know if having a `char` array for a large continuous sequence of known values with different data-types is a common practice.

Please forgive me if the question is badly phrased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is common practice. There are a couple of exceptional rules for `char` that make such usage possible. For example there is ([cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast)):

> Type aliasing
>
> Whenever an attempt is made to read or modify the stored value of an object of type DynamicType through a glvalue of type AliasedType, the behavior is undefined unless one of the following is true:
>
> [...]
>
> - AliasedType is std::byte, (since C++17)char, or unsigned char: **this permits examination of the object representation of any object as an array of bytes.**

Hence you can store objects as an array of `char` and retrieve them back, but the same wouldn't be possible with eg an array of `int` even though on the lowest level both are just bits and bytes.

Answer (score 2):

It is common practice to receive data as a byte array (char array) and then interpret the data according to some criteria. For example:

```
char buffer[512];

read(fd, buffer, 512);

if(buffer[0]==0xAD) {
    struct something *p= (struct something *)buffer;
    printf("%d\n",p->count);
}
else if (buffer[0]==0xBB) {
    int *pi= (int *)(buffer+12);
    printf("%d\n",*pi);
}
```

After reading some data into the buffer, the buffer is checked for some marker, here a hypothetical `0xAD`, and if equal, the buffer is interpreted as containing a struct `something`.

In the `else` part, the marker means that at byte position 12 there will be an int.